# Social Icon Hover

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to figure out how I can make a monochrome social icon have different colors when you hover over it. I've done everything imaginable and haven't had much luck. Thank you, in advance.

```
.social {
            position: fixed;
            top: -25;
            right: 0;
            padding: 20px;
            z-index:99
            }

    .social ul {
        overflow: auto;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    .social ul li {
        float: left;
    }

    .social img {
        padding: 7px;
        }

    .social img:hover {
         filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
         -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
         }

<div class="social">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" target="blank"><img src="img/social/fb.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="blank"><img src="img/social/twitter.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="blank"><img src="img/social/soundscloud.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="blank"><img src="img/social/spotify.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="blank"><img src="img/social/instagram.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="blank"><img src="img/social/youtube.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you define precisely what you mean by 'different colours when [we] hover over [the icon]'?

Comment: Ever considered using something like `fontastic` or `fontawesome`? You can do this really easy with this.

Comment: Have you thought about using different background-images and change these with `li:hover`?

Although you could achieve this by rendering the images both as colored and greyscale version, add `position:relative` to your li's,  then use the wished normal image as u've done so far and add 

`<span><img src="omg/social/youtube-hover.png"></span>`.

 Then you define your span with `li span {display: none; position: absolute}`and define for `li:hover span {display: block};`

As a workaround solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Try to use [fontastic.me](http://fontastic.me) or any other icon font for this.**

You can use icon fonts to make it simple. So all you'll need to do is (just for example):

```
<i class="icon icon-facebook"></i>
```

And styles:

```
.icon { 
color: red; 
}
.icon:hover { 
color: green; 
}
```

Comment: Sadly, I can't for this project. But I created an account. Thank you for the future reference.

Comment: Ok, the other way is to use png sprites.

Comment: Yes, you can fill it with the color you need and change the background position to another one on hover.

Comment: I mean trying to spend my entire night doing that and no results produced. It's driving me nuts mate.

Comment: That's why you'd better try icon font. Try Bootstrap icons, Foundation, Iconmoon or Fontastic.me. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.social ul li a:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: url(grayscale.svg); /* Firefox 4+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE 6-9 */
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cmx4uh11/

Comment: Did You checked jsFiddle link?

Comment: Here: http://unidevelopment.pl (on the bottom) You have example of hovering on images and changing them from grayscale to color.

Comment: Wow! It worked on the jsFiddle....but not for me. Which must mean something is blocking the code from passing through.

Comment: Hm... did You set the selector on Your `a` tag (.social ul li a:hover) ?

Comment: What browser you are using?

Comment: The new Safari for Yosemite.

Comment: Have you tried the CSS I posted, @Sterling?

For Safari, `.social li a img {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.social li a img:hover {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
filter: grayscale(0);
}`

ought to work fine.

Comment: @SterlingSavariau Did You checked other browsers?

Comment: @SterlingSavariau And, can You copy and send Your code on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.social li a img {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
-ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
-o-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.social li a img:hover {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
-moz-filter: grayscale(0);
-ms-filter: grayscale(0);
-o-filter: grayscale(0);
filter: grayscale(0);
}
```